# Wordpress 3.6 and Accordion UI issues?

Tags: jquery, updates

Anyone else having issues with WordPress 3.6 and the Accordion UI?

I have a website that was working just fine till I updated it to WordPress 3.6. The accordion menu stopped working. No errors.

Enqueue

```
wp_register_script('accordion',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/accordion.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-accordion'), 1.0, true);
```

My JS

```
jQuery('#accordion').accordion({ 
    heightStyle: 'content', 
    collapsible: true, 
    active: false
});
```

Nothing happens at all when I click on the accordion links. Everything loads, correctly. No errors. I heard about issues with WordPress 3.6 and jQuery UI - but have not been able to find anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's because "accordion" all of the sudden became a reserved word in wordpress. But once I switched my wp_enqueue_script/wp_register_script handle from accordion to myaccordion - everything worked.

Comment: **Probably** clashes with `$scripts->add( 'accordion', "/wp-admin/js/accordion$suffix.js", array( 'jquery' ), false, 1 );` from `wp-includes/script-loader.php`.

Comment: Yeah, it's just weird that it was working before the update but not after.

Comment: The line wasn't present in the previous WordPress version.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can use the Jquery UI (1.10.3) already embedded in Wordpress 3.6, with just:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

Comment: It is already being added as a dependency.

Comment: As I said, AS ALTERNATIVE, instead using your jquery-ui file in your template directory, you just could use the Wordpress version, already embedded in, with only one line as I wrote above.